# "Wrong number or types of arguments" in nativeQuery with temporal parameter set to null

Tags: hibernate, jpa, stored-procedures, oracle11g, nativequery

Given the following Oracle SQL stored procedure signature:

```sql
PROCEDURE Update_Desactivation_Date(
    code_util              IN NUMBER,
    t_no_piste             IN VARCHAR2,
    date_depart            IN DATE);
```

Called from a Java JPA2 Hibernate context using the following code:

```java
entityManager.createNativeQuery("CALL Update_Desactivation_Date(
        + ":code_util, "
        + ":t_no_piste, "
        + ":date_depart"
        + ")")
    .setParameter("code_util", 30320)
    .setParameter("t_no_piste", "087046")
    .setParameter("date_depart", null)
    .executeUpdate();
```

The execution yields the following exception:

```
WARN : org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 6553, SQLState: 65000
ERROR: org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'UPDATE_DESACTIVATION_DATE'

Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1214)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1147)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1224)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:108)
    at com.sw.chuv.badges.backend.dao.ExecuteUpdateInProcedure.main(ExecuteUpdateInProcedure.java:25)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.executeNativeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1310)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.executeUpdate(SQLQueryImpl.java:396)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.internalExecuteUpdate(QueryImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:99)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'UPDATE_DESACTIVATION_DATE'

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1044)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1329)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3584)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3665)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1352)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:210)
    ... 5 more
```

How comes, since all parameters are set correctly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `null` value for the date parameter is the culprit. You have to send an empty string:

```java
entityManager.createNativeQuery("CALL Update_Desactivation_Date("
        + ":code_util, "
        + ":t_no_piste, "
        + ":date_depart"
        + ")")
    .setParameter("code_util", 30320)
    .setParameter("t_no_piste", "087046")
    .setParameter("date_depart", "")
    .executeUpdate();
```

This issue appears with all temporal types (`DATE`, `TIME`, `TIMESTAMP`)

Answer (score 1):

An other possibility is to define a default parameter in your SQL procedure:

```
PROCEDURE Update_Desactivation_Date(
      code_util              IN NUMBER,
      t_no_piste             IN VARCHAR2,
      date_depart            IN DATE DEFAULT NULL);
```

Comment: Agreed, that would be a pretty solution, but this procedure is part of a legacy DB that we can not modify.